# How get / set fourcc in opencv?

Tags: visual-c++, opencv

I'm going to get fourcc and set fourcc to apply new recorded file with opencv.

For this I tried to get fourcc of original with '.get' of opencv,

and set the fourcc with 'VideoWriter vdoRec(vRecFileName, vFourcc, vFpc, frmSource.size(), true);'

instead 'VideoWriter vdoRec(vRecFileName, CV_FOURCC('W','M','V','1'), vFpc, frmSource.size(), true);'

Here, the vFourcc, vFpc  got with

```
int vFourcc = vdoCap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC);
double vFpc = vdoCap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
```

But it made error.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Looks like you have the codec ('W','M','V','1') installed, but the codec 'vFourcc' which was used to encode the original is not present on your machine.